# Can you create a connection between a Java Application to an Access database and while uploading the database to my website

Tags: java, mysql, file-upload, netbeans

I have written a few Java Applications offline before connecting to an Access Database but if I upload the database to a website and change the connection from `e://` (filepath) to the file path of a webpage, would this work?

What would be the easiest way to connect to an online database?

This application would need to include:

```
Name
Password
```

Then Teams involved with each person registered

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you:

> The Easysoft JDBC-ODBC Bridge provides JDBC access from Java applets,
>   applications or application servers to ODBC databases such as
>   Microsoft SQL Server, Microsoft Access and so on.
>
> Being a Type 3 client/server solution allows the Java applications and
>   ODBC drivers to be on separate machines.
>
> The client driver is 100% Java, eliminating the hassle of client side
>   ODBC drivers. It is compatible with any third party ODBC driver and
>   gives concurrent access to multiple data sources from multiple client
>   devices.
>
> Importantly, it is built for commercial use with high transaction
>   rates and dependable performance.

http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/jdbc_odbc_bridge/index.html?gclid=COexrKf8h70CFagKwwod3UUAdA